# Diagnostics for logistic regression and how to include/interpret interactions between categorical and continous variables?

Tags: regression, logistic, aic

I am working on a project that aims to identify the factors that affect the probability of detecting targets placed in different habitats in aerial photographs. I have done a lot of reading concerning how I should analyze the data I collected for my project, but have noticed some problems that I don’t know how to address. I will start by giving some background and then I’ll describe the analysis I did along with the results.

Study design:  We collected 1500 aerial photos of 26 targets placed in six different habitats. There were seven test flights performed over a five day period. The targets were not moved between test flights, but the flight path was changed. The photos were then divided between five people who went through them and recorded whether they found a target and the corresponding pixel coordinates. Each person was shown a mixture of photos where targets were present or absent. No photo was looked at more than once. I treated each target in a photo as a sampling unit, and assumed they were independent because no photo was looked at more than once and the observers were unaware of the locations of the targets.  Once all photos had been looked at, the survey responses were analysed to see what affected the probability of observers successfully identifying a target (success=1, failure=0).

Analysis: I used logistic regression models to anaylze my data with target detection as my binary response variable. There were three discrete variables (shutter speed, experience level, and habitat type) and two continuous variables (altitude and distance from the centerline) included in the model. Only photos with targets present were included in the analysis. All false positive target detections were discarded as well. When participants correctly identified a target it was labelled as a “success” and when they failed to find the target it was labelled as “failure” coded as 1 and 0, respectively. I used stepwise AIC to choose a model that best fit the data using the ‘step’ command in R.  My base model was just the intercept and the full model included all of the variables above, including the interaction terms. For categorical variables, interaction terms were only considered estimable if there were at least five records for every combination of the two covariate categories. The interaction terms included in the analysis were altitude x distance from centerline, altitude x habitat type, altitude x observer’s experience level, altitude x shutter speed, distance from centerline x habitat type, distance from centerline x observer’s experience level, distance from centerline x shutter speed.

Results:

Of the five primary variables and the seven interaction terms considered, the best fitting model included camera shutter speed and habitat type.. The final logistic regression model was ln (Pr(detection) / (1 -Pr(detection)) = 1.6412 -3.2865(habitat = heavy cover) -1.1937(habitat= Medium cover)+1.6992 (habitat= Open)+2.0573(shutter speed=1/800). The AIC value was 525.3. Targets in burned habitat were identified more often than targets located in heavy cover (p<0.0001, SE=5086) and medium cover (p=0.0012, SE=0.3699) and less often than targets in open habitat (p=0.0107, SE=0.6666). Targets were identified more often in photographs wen the camera shutter speed was set to 1/800 compared to a shutter speed of 1/1000 (p=0.0001,SE=0.5367).

Questions:

1. Can I treat each target in a photo as an independent sampling unit? I assumed that I could because they were never observed more than once , and their position would be slightly different in each photo because of the change in the flight path. I am not sure this is true though, since they were never repositions between trials. A colleague suggested that I should look into using mixed effect logistic regression instead?
2. Is it appropriate to include interaction terms between continuous and categorical variables? The graphs make me think that something strange is going on.
3. Looking at the relationships between my variables makes me think that something weird is going on, and I am looking for some feedback. What is the best way to do diagnotics on logistic regression models?
4. Is there a better way to approach my analysis/ further reading you would suggest?

Here are the graphs:

- Correlation matrix : ![https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwOV7.jpg
  -one of my graphs: ![https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hBMf.png